# How to remove persistent suggested URLs in Chrome on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Whenever I click the address bar of an existing tab in Chrome, in shows a list of suggested sites, before I even start typing. That would be helpful if these suggestions were accurate, but there are entries I didn't actually visit *that* often compared to others. There is even one entry I removed completely from my History.
How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your settings?  There should be a checkbox to turn that off.

Comment: Nope... You can only completely turn off search suggestions, but I don't want that. I just want to remove the wrong suggestions...

Comment: That's problem associated with Google search engine.

Comment: @Biswa, thank you for your input, but do have any recommendations on how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear recent searches from search bar in Chrome?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82147/how-can-i-clear-recent-searches-from-search-bar-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the arrow on the right of the suggested site that you want to delete and the adrress will be filled. You will now have the filled address and bellow some other suggestions from that site, but now, if you kepp you finger one of two seconds over the suggested site a pop up message will appear asking you if you want to delete the sugeste site. That it. [image]
[image]